# To determine the type of a singularity of a 2-D dynamic system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

This is a problem in my course homework. Suppose that $a>0$, $b>0$, considering the following 2-dimensional autunomous system:

$$\begin{align}\frac{dx_1}{dt}&=F(x_1)=a-x_1-\frac{4x_1x_2}{1+x_1^2},\\
         \frac{dx_2}{dt}&=G(x_2)=bx_1(1-\frac{x_2}{1+x_1^2}).
\end{align}$$

If $b<3t-\frac{5}{t}$, I want to determine the type of the only singularity of the system and its stability.

According to perron's theorem, if certain conditions is satisfied, the structure near the singularity is similar to its corresponding linear part system. So we analysis the Jacobian matrix.

It's not hard to see that $\left(t, 1+t^2\right)$ is the only singularity of the system, where $t=\frac{a}{5}$. Futhermore, the Jacobian matrix at the singularity is
$$\frac{\partial(F,G)}{\partial(x_1,x_2)}(t,1+t^2)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{3t^2-5}{t^2+1}&\frac{-4t}{1+t^2}\\\frac{2bt^2}{t^2+1}&\frac{-bt}{t^2+1}\end{pmatrix}.$$

the characteristic polynomial of the matrix is
$$(t^2 + 1)\lambda^2 + (bt - 3t^2 + 5)\lambda + 5bt$$
the discriminant is
$$\Delta=b^2t^2 - 26bt^3 - 10bt + 9t^4 - 30t^2 + 25$$
However, if my calculation is right, I can't determine how the singularity would be, so I need to discuss all the possible case the singularity could be.

Validation of my calculation or a complete answer to the question would be appreciated.